# Opening a session on your operating system

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop

I was looking at how windows provides tools like this called Remote Desktop Connection. Then I wondered, how would of this been accomplished. First most likely a socket connection is made between the two computers, but then how is a usable session opened. How could I do this in Java or Python?

My goal is to make one of these for connections over the internet protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Research the protocol RDP which underpins the remote desktop connection support.   Libraries exist to assist in using RDP in many different programming languages when you get to that point.